# ASP CSS Footer issue

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

Here is how my master page is designed:

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="container">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div id="header">
        <h1 class="Title">Title</h1>
        <span class="TagLine">tagline</span> </div>
      <div id="navigation">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><asp:Menu ID="m" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Items>
                  <asp:MenuItem Text="Home" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                </Items>
              </asp:Menu></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div id="body">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"> 
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
      </div>
      <div id="Footer">
        <p>footer</p>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

This is my css:

```
    body {
        margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
        color: darkslategrey;
        width: 960px;
        background-color: #F8F8FF;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    #container {
        min-height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #header {
        height: 120px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #Content {
        margin: 5px;
        background-color: #F8F8FF;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #Footer {
        position: absolute;
        background: #F8F8FF;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #header .Title {
        color: #2E2E2E;
    }
    #header h1 {
        padding-top: 1em;
        background-color: #F8F8FF;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-size: 170%;
    }
    h1 {
        padding-top: 1em;
        background-color: #F8F8FF;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-size: 100%;
    }
    #header .TagLine {
        color: #2E2E2E;
    }
    .Menu li {
        display: inline;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    .Menu a {
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #BDBDBD;
        padding: 5px;
        color: White;
        border-right: .5px solid White;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    .Menu a:hover {
        background-color: #BDBDBD;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    .Menu {
        text-align: justify;
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    .menuhover {
        color: #fff;
    }
```

Here are issues I am not able to figure:

- I am trying to stick footer at bottom, but such a
  way that if page has lot of content that should still work.
- Center align whole page and master page

Comment: possibilities

1-) content{ padding-top: 1em; //try to remove it

} 

2-) body { padding:10px; // play with it}

share you feedback so I can help you more

Comment: Doesn't help. Tried removing padding from content and removed #body from css. Still the same. I've removed same from initial question css as well.

Comment: #header h1 &  h1 also have padding-top:1em try this one too may be it willwork

Comment: I think i figured that was  /*margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;*/ in #header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated : Try this

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div id="header">
                <h1 class="Title">Title</h1>
                <span class="TagLine">tagline</span>
            </div>
            <div id="navigation">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="1000" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" CssClass="Menu" Font-Names="Verdana" ForeColor="Black" Width="800px">
                                <staticmenuitemstyle height="40px" />
                                <dynamicmenuitemstyle cssclass="Menu" height="40px" horizontalpadding="25px" />
                                <dynamichoverstyle cssclass="menuhover" />
                                <statichoverstyle cssclass="menuhover" />
                                <items>
                                    <asp:menuitem text="Home" navigateurl="~/Default.aspx"></asp:menuitem>
                                </items>
                            </asp:Menu>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="body">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
                    <!-- Page-specific content will go here... -->
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
            <div id="Footer">
                <p>footer</p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">

    body {
        margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
        color: darkslategrey;
        width: 960px;
        background-color: #F8F8FF;
        margin: auto;
        padding:auto;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    #container {
        min-height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #body {
        padding: 10px;
    }
    #header {
        margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
        height: 120px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #Content {
        padding-top: 1em;
        margin: 5px;
        background-color: #F8F8FF;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #Footer {
        position: fixed;
        background: #F8F8FF;
        text-align: center;
        bottom:0px;

    }
    #header .Title {
        color: #2E2E2E;
    }
    #header h1 {
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        background-color: #F8F8FF;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-size: 170%;
    }
    h1 {
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
        background-color: #F8F8FF;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-size: 100%;
    }
    #header .TagLine {
        color: #2E2E2E;
    }
    .Menu li {
        display: inline;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    .Menu a {
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #BDBDBD;
        padding: 5px;
        color: White;
        border-right: .5px solid White;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    .Menu a:hover {
        background-color: #BDBDBD;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    .Menu {
        text-align: justify;
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    .menuhover {
        color: #fff;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: that works perfectly fine. One question though. Whats the use of wrapping css content inside <style type="text/css"></style>. If I remove those tags look changes a lot

Comment: The <style> tag is used to define style information for an HTML document.

Inside the <style> element you specify how HTML elements should render in a browser.(CSS)

Each HTML document can contain multiple <style> tags.

Answer (score 0):

I have figure out your spacing issue.

1. spacing issue is related to **line-height**. You will set line height for h1

   ## header h1 {

   ```
   padding-top: 1em;
   background-color: #F8F8FF;
   overflow: hidden;
   font-size: 170%;
   line-height: 21px;
   ```

   }
2. Same issue with content and navigation menu.
3. Sticky footer : You will add **position: fixed;** and **bottom:0;**
4. Center align whole page and master page. You will add two more property in body css

   body {
       margin: 0 auto;
       width: 80%;
   }